# Error while interpreting .tflite file of ssd_resnet50 object detection model

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection-api, tensorflow-lite, tensorflow-ssd

The error is `Kernal Restarting: The kernel appears to have died. It will restart automatically.` Am following the steps as mentioned [here](https://github.com/rehmanzafar/ssd-resnet-to-tflite). The kernel crashes on executing `interpreter.invoke()` - in the code below.

Am running the code through Jupyter Notebook with Tensorflow 1.14.0

Edit 1: When I run the same code for a .tflite file of a binary classification model it works fine.

```
interpreter = tf.lite.Interpreter(model_path=PATH_TO_MODEL)
interpreter.allocate_tensors()

# Get input and output tensors.
input_details = interpreter.get_input_details()
output_details = interpreter.get_output_details()

# Load image for testing
image = cv2.imread(os.path.join(os.getcwd(),IMAGE_NAME))

input_data_f32 = np.array(image, dtype=np.float32)
input_data = np.expand_dims(input_data_f32, axis=0)
interpreter.set_tensor(input_details[0]['index'], input_data)

interpreter.invoke()

output_data = interpreter.get_tensor(output_details[0]['index'])
```

Comment: Do you need to check the input/output shapes and dtypes for your .tflite model?

Comment: No. I want to compare the performance of the .tflite file against a checkpoint file